# SSIS Script to Loop through downloading multiple zip files

Tags: http, download, ssis, foreach-loop-container

I have a SSIS package in which I use a Scipt Task with VB (see code below) and a Http Connection Manager to download 1 defined .zip file.  What I am hoping to do and can't figure out is to loop through and download all the .zip files in that same location.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the Visual B:

```
    Imports System
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Text
    Imports System.Windows.Forms
    Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime

     Public Sub Main()
    '
    ' Get the unmanaged connection object, from the connection manager called "HTTP Connection Manager"
    Dim nativeObject As Object = Dts.Connections("HTTP Connection Manager").AcquireConnection(Nothing)

    ' Create a new HTTP client connection
    Dim connection As New HttpClientConnection(nativeObject)


    ' Download the file #1
    ' Save the file from the connection manager to the local path specified
    Dim filename As String = "C:\Users\{CurrentUser}\Documents\file.zip"
    connection.DownloadFile(filename, True)

    ' Confirm file is there
    If File.Exists(filename) Then
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("File {0} has been downloaded.", filename))
    End If


    ' Download the file #2
    ' Read the text file straight into memory
    Dim buffer As Byte() = connection.DownloadData()
    Dim data As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer)

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you using loop containers?

Comment: I was going to use foreach loop container.

Answer (score 0):

Use a ForEachLoop container and populate variables with the information your script needs to work.  Then access the variables in the script.